# Spring Web: Mapping URL to a standalone Spring app

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, web-applications, spring-web

I have two standalone Spring Boot/Web web app .jars, A and B, both made by third-parties, with their own URL mappings which I do not know about in advance.

I would like to create a setup where "localhost:8080/A" maps (passes through) to A's "/" mapping. Similarly, "localhost:8080/B" should pass through to B's "/" mapping.

Additional mappings, which again I don't necessarily know about in advance, should also pass through respectively - so "localhost:8080/A/items" should pass through to A's "/items", etc.

I do not have the source code for A or B, only .jar files.

For security, A and B should have separate scopes with no knowledge of each other or ability to interact with each other. The whole setup should behave as if A and B were separate "inner" servers within my "outer" localhost server.

Can this be achieved via a Spring Boot/Web wrapper or gateway app, or some other way?

Answer (score 0):

You could use spring boot with Zuul as a third app, running on 8080, which has routes setup for A and B similar to what you described.

```
zuul:
  routes:
    app-A:
      path: /A/**
      url: http://localhost:8081/
    app-B:
      path: /B/**
      url: http://localhost:8082/
```

That configuration (application.yml) of your third app would point "A" traffic to port 8081 and "B" traffic to port 8082.

This is quick and dirty, but should get you started.

Alternatively, you could use spring cloud gateway, to get a similar type of setup with the additional ability to do sockets/reactive.